# Change date format in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a date in different format. And i wanted to show it in a different format. And i wanted to do it on client side. Is there any way to convert the format.

```
Date : 2013-07-30 16:12:13.0
Expected Format :Jul 30, 2013 4:12 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use MomentJS, great for time formatting:

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [jquery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) that is pretty much duplication read this article: [JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)